# Translation of "garden shears"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

[Garden shears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_shears) (pruning shears) are specialized scissors used in gardening. Loppers are a bigger, two-handed version used to cut larger branches. Are there specific terms in Spanish to refer to these tools, or would they all be considered *tijeras*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called **tijeras de podar**, **tijeras de jardinero**, or **podaderas**.

I would say **tijeras de jardinero** is mostly used for the big ones, but there aren't really different words for pruning shears and loppers.

According to Laura (in Majorca?): Garden shears = **tijeras de podar**, loppers = **tijeras de fuerza** (this term is unknown to me).

Comment: Actually there are different words. Garden shears = tijeras de podar, loppers= tijeras de fuerza

Comment: @Laura: Added, thanks. I put it as a regionalism, please correct if it isn't so (I "communitied" the answer).

Comment: I really don't know if it's a regionalism. I work in gardening so I have a name for every tool, but I don't know anymore if they're technicall, common, regional... :D